# Couldnot inflate maps activity in tabbed activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I tried inflating google maps activity in my tabbed activity. There is no compile time or run-time error on my application. The problem is that, i cannot see the marker, just the layout is inflated. 
Here is code of my MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_page, container, false);
        RelativeLayout mainview = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        int num;

        RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        num= getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        if (num==1){
            View child = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.maps_activity, null);
            myLayout.addView(child);

        } else if (num==2){

        } else if (num==3){

        } else{

        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

Here is my maps_activity.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.codestarsnepal.aashish.know_your_air.KnowYourAir" />
```

Here is my MapsActivity.java

```
public class KnowYourAir extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_know_your_air);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

Comment: is the map showing?

Comment: yes the map is being displayed. but doesnot shows the marker.